# Lodash filter Array of Objects using multiple properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, lodash

How do i filter an array with multiple conditions ?

```js
var users = [
  { user: "barney", age: 36, active: true },
  { user: "fred", age: 39, active: false },
  { user: "fred", age: 40, active: false },
  { user: "fred", age: 41, active: false },
  { user: "fred", age: 42, active: false },
  { user: "fred", age: 43, active: false },
]
_.filter(users, function (o) {
  return o.age !== 40 || o.age !== 41 || o.age !== 42
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You probably want `&&`, not `||`, as your condition will be true for all numeric values of `o.age`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small problem with your predicate function

```
o.age !== 40 || o.age !== 41 || o.age !== 42
```

pass every object because age only have one value, so it is definitely true to check if it is different from 3 different values

Below fix could help you

```js
var users = [
  { user: "barney", age: 36, active: true },
  { user: "fred", age: 39, active: false },
  { user: "fred", age: 40, active: false },
  { user: "fred", age: 41, active: false },
  { user: "fred", age: 42, active: false },
  { user: "fred", age: 43, active: false },
]

const res = _.filter(users, function (o) {
  return ![40, 41, 42].includes(o.age)
})

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```